# java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: not null but: was null - Junit teste

Tags: junit, mockito

A variável **result** está retornando **NULL** apesar do Objeto está preenchido.

Esse é meu teste;

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class IndicioDAOTest {

    @Mock
    private IndicioDAO indicioDAO;

    @Test
    public void findByIdIndicio() {

        IndicioEntity entity = criarIndicioEntity();

        IndicioEntity result = indicioDAO.getPorId(entity.getCodigo());

        assertThat(result, notNullValue());

    }

    private IndicioEntity criarIndicioEntity() {

        TipoIndicioEntity tipoIndicio = new TipoIndicioEntity();
        tipoIndicio.setCodigo(1);

        NaturezaIndicioEntity naturezaIndicio = new NaturezaIndicioEntity();
        naturezaIndicio.setCodigo(1);

        SituacaoIndicioEntity situacaoIndicio = new SituacaoIndicioEntity();
        situacaoIndicio.setCodigo(1);

        PessoaJuridicaPublicaEntity pessoaJuridicaPublicaEntity = new PessoaJuridicaPublicaEntity();

        pessoaJuridicaPublicaEntity.setCodigo(1);

        IndicioEntity entity = new IndicioEntity();
        entity.setCodigo(1);
        entity.setTipoIndicio(tipoIndicio);
        entity.setUnidadeJurisdicionada(pessoaJuridicaPublicaEntity);
        entity.setCodigoNaturezaIndicio(naturezaIndicio.getCodigo());
        entity.setCpfServidor("80445500700");
        entity.setDescricao("qualquer valor dentro");
        entity.setValor(1500.0);
        entity.setPrazo(15);
        entity.setSituacaoAtual(situacaoIndicio);
        entity.setDataUltimaMovimentacao(getDataAtual());
        return entity;
    }

}
```

Observe a imagem de uma execução em debug;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém meu objeto está preenchido;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de ajuda para corrigir o bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está chamando um método do `indicioDAO`, que é um `@Mock`.

O comportamento padrão de um `@Mock` será sempre retornar nulo, ele é um objeto utilitário para verificações e simulação de retornos, exceções, entre outras coisas.

Em resumo, você **sempre deve dizer ao mock o que ele deve fazer**.

Então, para retornar algum valor, você deveria utilizar dessa forma:

```
Mockito.when(indicioDAO.getPorId(entity.getCodigo())).thenReturn(entity);
```

Quando houver a chamada `getPorId`, passando o código da entidade, será retornada a entidade.

Isso resolveria seu problema, mas não acredito que este seja um teste válido, sendo que você está dizendo explicitamente o que a DAO irá retornar, e verificar se o valor retornado é o valor que você mandou o mock retornar.

Comment: Você tem razão, o teste passou, mas como eu poderia verificar se o valor retornado é o valor que eu mandei para o mock?

Comment: Já vi como é, não precisa.... mesmo assim muito obrigado.